# New to node.js and I'm not sure if I'm doing this correct

Tags: node.js

So, the code works, but the indent level is insane... With all the callbacks in node, how exactly should I be coding?

```
"use strict";

var crypto = require('crypto'),
    fs     = require('fs'),
    mmm    = require('mmmagic'),
    Magic  = require('mmmagic').Magic,
    path   = require('path');

console.log('Init controller: ' + path.basename(__filename));

exports.help = function () {
    var help;

    help  = "POST http://server/images\n";
    help += "    Upload image for storage.\n";
    help += "    <image> - The image file to upload\n";
    help += "    <title> - The title of the image, no more than 50 characters\n";
    help += "    <desc>  - The description of the image, no more than 1024 characters\n";

    return help;
}

exports.post = function (req, res) {
    var image = req.files.image;
    if (typeof(image) == 'undefined') {
        res.status(400).send("{error:'Upload error'}");
        return;
    }

    var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
    magic.detectFile(image.path, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send("{error:'Upload mime error'}");
        } else {
            var mime = result.toLowerCase().split('/');

            if (mime[0] != 'image') {
                res.status(400).send("{error:'Upload not an image', mime: '" + result + "'}");
            } else {
                // Read the image file
                fs.readFile(image.path, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(400).send("{error:'Upload read error'}");
                    } else {
                        var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest("hex");
                        req.app.models.image.count({'hash': hash}, function (err, count) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.status(400).send("{error:'ORM Error: '" + JSON.stringify(err) + "'}");
                            } else {
                                if (count > 0) {
                                    res.status(400).send("{error:'Image already exists'}");
                                } else {
                                    var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest("hex");
                                    var newPath = path.join(req.app.tempDir, hash);
                                    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
                                        if (err) {
                                            res.status(400).send("{error:'Upload write error'}");
                                        } else {
                                            // Save the image
                                            req.app.models.image.create([{
                                                'hash'      : hash,
                                                'mime'      : mime,
                                                title       : '',
                                                description : ''
                                            }], function(err, images) {
                                                if (err) {
                                                    fs.unlink(newPath);
                                                    res.status(400).send("{error:'" + err.message + "'}");
                                                } else {
                                                    res.status(200).send("{id:'" + images[0].id + "}");
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Lots of folks will recommend various libraries to help deal with async code; I go over one, called async, that you may find helpful: http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously (callback management starts at about 3:54)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://callbackhell.com/ has a guide to adjusting to asynchronous programming.

Some follow-ups from the comments:

- There are projects such as [Node Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) and [Iced CoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/) if making asynchronous code look like top-down synchronous code appeals to you and the being misled by that illusion doesn't make you very nervous. However, I strongly recommend working with regular javascript and async programming with callbacks (not promises) until the light bulb goes on before exploring solutions to a "problem" you don't really understand.
- Asynchronous code is a bunch of bits of code that execute when the OS is done with I/O. That's why it doesn't read top-down - because it doesn't execute top-down. It executes whenever the IO is done which is why it scales the way it does.
- Don't be misled by beginner snippets. Go look at code by the masters like TJ Holowaychuk before deciding that asynchronous code is unreadable. Callback hell is a beginner phenomenon. It is extremely prevalent. Almost everyone goes through it as a phase, but it's not particularly difficult to get beyond, especially given the alternative of mastering multithreaded locking and semaphores and the debugging thereof. Async code that reads well is often just straight-up better-designed code all around. But yes, it lacks the top-down orderliness of synchronous code and that means more jumping around in the source.

Comment: This doesn't seem sane. I'm going to create a bunch of functions, that will only ever be called from one spot. Then in the "main" method, in this case the exports.post, I'll have to flip all over the file to these one off functions to follow the code flow. I'm not sure I like either of the options, a ton of one off functions, or huge indents.

Comment: It's different. Calling it "insane" because it's unfamiliar to you is short-sighted. It's definitely challenging compared to synchronous code, but remember it's not fair to compare a set of blocking synchronous code to asynchronous code. If you want a comparison, you MUST use a multithreaded blocking example to at least compare comparable functionality, in which case the asynchronous example is usually going to scale drastically farther.

Comment: I suppose. My issue is having a ton of functions that encapsulate a single if/else. I guess I'm envisioning a file will 100 tiny functions that just call one another in order never to be used anywhere else.

Comment: Change your thought paradigm from "where" to "when". "This function executes when the data is read from disk". "This function executes when the database query returns". The code looks like that because that's how asynchronous, event-driven code executes. Best to just get comfortable with it or look into something like Fibers/IcedCoffeeScript if you want a leaky abstraction that makes it look like synchronous top-down code.

Answer (score 2):

`<shamelessPlug>`

I went through the process of callback spaghetti --> promise spaghetti --> wrote my own promise management library

[That library is available here](https://github.com/bguiz/qryq)

[... and this describes the above process in a bit more detail](https://github.com/bguiz/qryq/blob/master/doco/present/markdown/present.md)

`</shamelessPlug>`

In any case, the general answer is yes - you will eventually wind up with a mess of callbacks. To stop that from happening, you are best served by a callback management system or promises.

Which method is the best? It really is up to you, and what you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I found that concept of promises helps here a lot. There are many implementations of promises in JavaScript, but idea is same. You can start from this one:

https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise

Answer (score 1):

Come one guys. Do you really think that you need a library for that. You can handle it with pure javascript. Here is the code rewritten:

```
var response = null,
    request = null;
var fileDetected = function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        response.status(400).send("{error:'Upload mime error'}");
    } else {
        var mime = result.toLowerCase().split('/');
        if (mime[0] != 'image') {
            response.status(400).send("{error:'Upload not an image', mime: '" + result + "'}");
        } else {
            // Read the image file
            fs.readFile(image.path, onReadFile);
        }
    }
}
var onReadFile = function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        response.status(400).send("{error:'Upload read error'}");
    } else {
        var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest("hex");
        request.app.models.image.count({'hash': hash}, onImageCount);
    }
}
var onImageCount = function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
        response.status(400).send("{error:'ORM Error: '" + JSON.stringify(err) + "'}");
    } else {
        if (count > 0) {
            response.status(400).send("{error:'Image already exists'}");
        } else {
            var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest("hex");
            var newPath = path.join(request.app.tempDir, hash);
            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, onFileWrite);
        }
    }
}
var onFileWrite = function(err) {
    if (err) {
        response.status(400).send("{error:'Upload write error'}");
    } else {
        // Save the image
        request.app.models.image.create([{
            'hash'      : hash,
            'mime'      : mime,
            title       : '',
            description : ''
        }], function(err, images) {
            if (err) {
                fs.unlink(newPath);
                response.status(400).send("{error:'" + err.message + "'}");
            } else {
                response.status(200).send("{id:'" + images[0].id + "}");
            }
        });
    }
}

exports.post = function (req, res) {
    request = req;
    response = res;
    var image = request.files.image;
    if (typeof(image) == 'undefined') {
        response.status(400).send("{error:'Upload error'}");
        return;
    }
    var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
    magic.detectFile(image.path, fileDetected);
}
```

The good part is that by separating everything in different functions you actually split your logic into blocks. The name of the newly created function speaks about the purpose of the block.

Comment: I can see this, but my issue with it and why I didn't do this in the first place is the global variables `response` and `request`. I can't seem to find any way to have them passed along to the callbacks. In truth I can't find any way to pass any variable to a callback.

Comment: Passing same arguments to callbacks is not very good. I mean you may end up with a lot of arguments. If you don't want to be global (and they are global only for the current module) then define a closure. Doing this you will keep them in a private scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to comment that something is "load the image" or "save the image", extracting those into separate functions would help the readability, decrease the indent level, and remove the need for comments.

I.e. instead of writing

```
// ... 
      petAHorse(function(horsesResponse) {
        // ...
      })
// ...
```

you can write

```
function horsePettedHandler(horsesResponse) {
  // ...
}

// ... 
      petAHorse(horsePettedHandler);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of promises I prefer to use [node-sync lib](https://github.com/0ctave/node-sync). Because it allow one great thing: you don't must wrap async libs functions for promises, you can just use it with special syntax. Like this:

```
var result = thirdPartyLibAsyncFunction.sync(null, 2, 3);
```

It work with your own code the same way.